# Should I be subclassing the CCSprite to schedule updates in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

The documentation says things like:

> Each node, by default, has no
>   updates. If you want to update the
>   state of your node you should schedule
>   a callback
>
> The recommended way to do it is by
>   calling CCNode scheduling methods, and
>   not by using NSTimer. CCNode has the
>   following method to timer
>
> scheduleUpdate
>   scheduleUpdateWithPriority:(int)priority
>   scheduleSelector:(SEL)selector
>   scheduleSelector:(SEL)selector
>   interval:(float)interval Properties of
>   these method:
>
> The scheduled callbacks will be called
>   only if the node is “on stage”, if the
>   node is part of a living scene The
>   scheduled callbacks won't be called if
>   the Director is paused You should not
>   DRAW anything in these methods They
>   will receive the delta time as an
>   argument

Note: I am reading 'update' as, change the state of the Sprite according to what needs to be happening next in the game for this frame.

Does this mean I am suppose to be subclassing the CCSprite and then giving it new implementation for the update method?

(If so, would I need to call the original overridden method explicitly?)

Source: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:draw_update

Comment: What are you looking to update in your sprite? You never need to call the draw method unless your using OpenGL commands. In my game, I use the tick: method from the box2d itterations, to called '[sprite update]' on every sprite that has a psychics body, I do this because I'm only using box2d for collision detection, not physics simulation however.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are talking about the game logic, and how it should update the sprite.

If that is the case, you should go with composition. Create a CCNode subclass, which has a CCSprite as an instance variable (Composition).

For more on this, read: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2010/06/prefer-composition-inheritance/